# keys do not move the object in the game written in python

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.4

Update: manish kumar gave me the solution for the problem. I had to write event.key instead of event.type in a certain part of the code.
 check it out at it below:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
```

I am trying to make a simple game by using Pygame.
Simply I have written code to move a car to the left and right.
Everything works well except that the keys do not move the car.

here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init() 

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

GD1 = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Racing!") 
clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

carimg = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/Abdulaziz/Downloads/my_app___car_sprite_5_by_nicolaspok-d65xysp.png")

def car(x,y):
    GD1.blit(carimg,(x,y))

x = (800 * 0.45)
y = (600 * 0.7)

x_change = 0

crashed = False 

while not crashed: 

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    GD1.fill(white)
    car(x,y)



    pygame.display.flip() 
    clock.tick(60) 
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

the problem is probably in this part of the code:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.type == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               x_change = 0
```

Again, the car appears but do not move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use event.key instead of event.type.

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            x_change = -5
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            x_change = 5


    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
           x_change = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies here:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    # modifications to x_change

x += x_change
```

If the call to `pygame.event.get()` returns two events, a KEYDOWN and a KEYUP, then `x_change` will be set to 5 or -5, but then it will be set back to 0.

You should update `x` at each iteration:

```
for event in pygame.event.get(): 
    # modifications to x_change

    x += x_change
```